# Group list of tuples by item

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-itertools

I have this list as example:

```
[(148, Decimal('3.0')), (325, Decimal('3.0')), (148, Decimal('2.0')), (183, Decimal('1.0')), (308, Decimal('1.0')), (530, Decimal('1.0')), (594, Decimal('1.0')), (686, Decimal('1.0')), (756, Decimal('1.0')), (806, Decimal('1.0'))]
```

Now i want to group by the id, so I will use `itemgetter(0)`:

```
import operator, itertools
from decimal import *
test=[(148, Decimal('3.0')), (325, Decimal('3.0')), (148, Decimal('2.0')), (183, Decimal('1.0')), (308, Decimal('1.0')), (530, Decimal('1.0')), (594, Decimal('1.0')), (686, Decimal('1.0')), (756, Decimal('1.0')), (806, Decimal('1.0'))]

for _k, data in itertools.groupby(test, operator.itemgetter(0)):
    print list(data)
```

I don't know why but I am getting this wrong output:

```
[(148, Decimal('3.0'))]
[(325, Decimal('3.0'))]
[(148, Decimal('2.0'))]
[(183, Decimal('1.0'))]
[(308, Decimal('1.0'))]
[(530, Decimal('1.0'))]
[(594, Decimal('1.0'))]
[(686, Decimal('1.0'))]
[(756, Decimal('1.0'))]
[(806, Decimal('1.0'))]
```

As you can see the output is not grouped by id. However the code above works fine if I use `itemgetter(1)`. The output is grouped by decimal val.

```
[(148, Decimal('3.0')), (325, Decimal('3.0'))]
[(148, Decimal('2.0'))]
[(183, Decimal('1.0')), (308, Decimal('1.0')), (530, Decimal('1.0')), (594, Decimal('1.0')), (686, Decimal('1.0')), (756, Decimal('1.0')), (806, Decimal('1.0'))]
```

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would first need to *sort* the data for the *groupby* to work, it groups *consecutive elements* based on the key you provide:

```
import operator, itertools
from decimal import *
test=[(148, Decimal('3.0')), (325, Decimal('3.0')), (148, Decimal('2.0')), (183, Decimal('1.0')), (308, Decimal('1.0')), (530, Decimal('1.0')), (594, Decimal('1.0')), (686, Decimal('1.0')), (756, Decimal('1.0')), (806, Decimal('1.0'))]

for _k, data in itertools.groupby(sorted(test), operator.itemgetter(0)):
    print list(data)
```

But you would be better using a dict to group to avoid an unnecessary O(n log n) sort:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for t in test:
    d[t[0]].append(t)

for v in d.values():
    print(v)
```

Both would give you the same groupings, just not necessarily in the same order.

Answer (score 2):

`itertools.groupby()` requires the data to be consistent or sorted.

`[(148, Decimal('3.0')), (148, Decimal('2.0')), (325, Decimal('3.0'))]` will work but `[(148, Decimal('3.0')), (325, Decimal('3.0')), (148, Decimal('2.0'))]` will not as the id is `148, 325, 148` instead of `148, 148, 325`.