# Group lists in python based on common elements

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists

```
list1 = [['1997', 0.56], ['1998', 0.62], ['1997', 0.78], ['1998', 0.23]]
```

I need to group them so that the new list looks like:

```
list2 = [['1997',0.56,0.78], ['1998', 0.62, 0.23]]
```

How can I achieve this using python?

Comment: Edit the question to show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39650110/group-list-of-tuples-by-item

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `groupby` from `itertools` module within a `list comprehension` like this example:

```
from itertools import groupby

list1 = [['1997', 0.56], ['1998', 0.62], ['1997', 0.78], ['1998', 0.23]]

result = [[k] +  [j[1] for j in list(v)] for k,v in groupby(sorted(list1, key=lambda x: x[0]), lambda x: x[0])]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[['1997', 0.56, 0.78], ['1998', 0.62, 0.23]]
```

Comment: Does this only work if I have only one item in the list of lists, what if I have more than 1 item 
    list1 = [['1997', 0.56, 0.67], ['1998', 0.62, 0,23], ['1997', 0.78, 0.65], ['1998', 0.23, 0.51]]

Comment: Yes this answer will work if you have only 2 elements in your sublists. If you want another solution, or an extension, please modify your question and add your new queries and let me now. I'll edit my answer in order to solve your new problem.